# createServerSocket returning java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to create a server socket using sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(port);

But its giving exception permission denied. Below is my complete code.

```
    private SSLServerSocket getSslServerSocket(int port)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyManager[] keyManager = this.mKeyStoreManager.getKeyManagers();
    TrustManager[] trustManager = this.mKeyStoreManager.getTrustManagers();
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManager, trustManager, (SecureRandom) null);
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = null;
    try {

        sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslContext
                .getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(port);
        sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        sslServerSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("----Exception", ex.getMessage());
    }

    return sslServerSocket;
}
```

I have tried multiple ports, but I am getting same error on all.

Below is the exception message.
java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Either you're trying to use a system port (<=1023) as per @JiangYD's answer, which shouldn't have been deleted, or you don't have enough access permission to do socket operations at all. I believe there is an Android configuration file you have to provide or package with the application to get these permissions.

Comment: I dont think there is any specific permission for socket programming in android and port numbers I have tried so far are 9090, 1060, 9252.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but if somebody else is searching for the solution: adding

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml should fix the problem